# Why does the p-value for z=x correspond to the negative x in a z-score table?

Tags: self-study

I was given the following problem on a practice final exam and I think the professor posted the wrong answer, but with the final tomorrow I don't have time to ask him via email so I figured I'd look for the solution here:

> Q. 7
>   A  sample  of
>   n
>   =  36  adults  participated  in  a  study  measuring  the  effectiveness  of  ginkgo  biloba  and
>   ginseng as tools for improving memory.  After 90 days of taking the supplements, these adults took a
>   standardized memory test.  Their average score on the test was  ̄
>   x
>   = 84.
>   a.
>   Compared to the general population, whose mean score on this test was
>   μ
>   = 80 with
>   σ
>   = 18, use
>   the critical-value approach to determine if there evidence that taking these supplements improves
>   memory when
>   α
>   = 0
>   .
>   05.
>   b.
>   What is the
>   p
>   -value for the test conducted in
>   a.
>   ?

answer to a:

z = 1.33 (which I got as well), Z0.05= 1.645,

answer to b:

p-value: p = 0.0918. **What I don't get is the p-value of 0.0918 corresponds to -1.33 from the Z score table.** How did he get that p-value? Is he correct?

Comment: What is the answer from your professor?

Comment: z = 1.33 (which I got as well), Z0.05= 1.645, p-value: p = 0.0918. What I don't get is the p-value of 0.0918 corresponds to -1.33 from the Z score table. How did he get that p-value? Is he correct?

Comment: I understand where he got both the critical value and p-value from, I just don't understand why he's using the negative Z-score table. Is it because of the significance level of 5%?

Comment: He did not really use the negative value although it looks like it. He used $$P(z>a) = 1-P(z<a)$$ which happens to be equal for distributions that are symmetric around zero, $$1-P(y<a)=P(y<-a)$$ The value $P(z<=a)$, the cumulative distribution function, is what you most commonly find in the tables (check which is the case). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function. BTW note the round of error. $1-P(z<=4/3)=0.0912$ is slightly different than $1-P(z<=1.33)=0.0918$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He did not really use the negative value although it looks like it. He used $$P(z \geq a) = 1-P(z < a)$$ which happens to be equal for continuous distributions that are symmetric around zero, $$1-P(y < a)=P(y \leq -a)$$ The value $P(z \leq a)$, the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), is what you most commonly find in the tables (check which is the case).

---

*BTW note the round--of-error.*

*$$1-P(z < 4/3)=0.0912$$  is slightly different than $$1-P(z < 1.33)=0.0918$$   (if you work with this precision, which I find a bit superfluous/exaggerated in this case, then also do it correctly)*

Answer (score 0):

$Z = \frac{(84 - 80)}{18 / \sqrt{36}} = 1.33$

Recall that a p-value is the probability of seeing something as or more extreme than your result. So, in this case, $P(Z > 1.33) = 1 - P(Z < 1.33) = P(Z < -1.33) = .0918$. The symmetry of the normal distribution allows you to use negative critical values if you're looking for the probability of Z being greater than a specific value: $P(Z > c) = P(Z < -c)$, where $c$ is a critical value.